# Ajax on admin side goes to 404 ( Not Found ) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, ajax, admin-panel, 404

I have created a button and want to save some data using Ajax but it goes to 404 not found.

My URL is http://127.0.0.1/magento/AdminSample/datasave/index/?isAjax=true

My controller file path is ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/Controller/Adminhtml/Datasave/Index.php )

```
<?php
namespace Tym17\AdminSample\Controller\Adminhtml\Datasave;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface; // Needed to retrieve config values

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
 protected $resultPageFactory;
/**
 * @var scopeConfig
 * Needed to retrieve config values
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig // Needed to retrieve config values
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig; // Needed to retrieve config values
}

/**
* Index Action*
* @return void
*/
public function execute()
{
    /*$post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    var_dump($post);*/
    die('a');
}
}
```

My JS file path is ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/view/adminhtml/web/js/adminscript.js )

My routes.xml file path ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="AdminSample" frontName="AdminSample">
        <module name="Tym17_AdminSample" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

My JS file is ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/view/adminhtml/web/js/adminscript.js )

```
require(["jquery","mage/url"],function($,url) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('123');
    url.setBaseUrl(BASE_URL);
    var BaseUrl = url.build('');
    jQuery( ".product" ).on( 'click', '.save',function() {
        console.log('click');
        let customurl = "http://127.0.0.1/magento/AdminSample/Datasave/index/";
        let dataid = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.dataid').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: customurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                dataid:dataid
            },
            complete: function(response) {             
                console.log('aaaaa');
            },
        });
    });
});
});
```

On clicking on button if i use console it shows the result but AJAX goes to 404.

What's the issue i didn't get this.Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your routes.xml for us as well?

Comment: Updated please check @joeybab3

Comment: Can you also post your js file that's making the ajax request?

Comment: Updated Please check @NSwanson7

Comment: @Prits it's something small, but have you tried changing `Datasave` to `datasave` in the url within your js file?

Comment: It still goes to 404 ( error : 404 Not Found ) @NSwanson7

Comment: @Prits Your customurl  is wrong that why 404 error comes. please get admin url proper.

Comment: share your phtml file how you are doing.